# Finding and deleting rows in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

How can I find and delete rows in Excel that start with a cell that has a value, and the cell below has a value as well.[Excel Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBIbE.png)
The screenshot attached shows some dummy data that I've got. In this example, the result I want is that rows 16, 17, 18 and 22 would all be removed from the file.

[image]

Comment: For this you need VBA macro so please [edit] your post & add your need also new TAG VBA !!

Comment: Oh. In that case I might need to find another solution. I'm doing this to help someone else with their data, but suggesting VBA probably won't go down well. Thanks for your comment though.

Comment: It isn't quite clear what the criteria for deletion is. In a grouping of rows with the same value in col C, say "individual", do you only want to keep the last "individual" in the group? Why not discard 24-26, as they are all in the "blank" group.

Comment: @Samuel,, then the only option lift is identify those rows & use Delete Row command from the menu !!

Answer (score 1):

Its not 100% clear what you are asking but try this.

In Cell F16 put:

`=IF(A17<>"","DELETE ME","")` and drag down

The filter column on column F, to show only "Delete Me" and delete away.

Comment: In the formula, F17 should be A17

Comment: I don't know where I got F from, the data only goes out to E :S

Answer (score 0):

The most convenient way to do this would require some VBA code - but you can still do this semi-manually. If you have to do this often, shortcut keys is a huge time saver.

**Overview:**

Imagine a helper column called "BLANK BELOW", that is TRUE (or "") for the rows to keep and FALSE (or "delete me") for the ones to delete. @PeterH's formula would do just fine.
Now **use a filter**, show only FALSE / "delete me" rows, **select** and **delete** the
rows entirely. Clear filter. And done!

Now, lets see how fast/automated we can make each step in bold.

**Faster Selecting:**

Selecting is usually done by dragging the mouse across the row numbers. This is fine for a few rows, but what if its pages full? Click the row number of the first data row to delete. Hold *Ctrl* + *Shift* and hit the *down arrow*.

You can go even one step further, and format the data as an table (see Home > "Format as table"). Now if you hit *Ctrl* + *A* (select all) while any cell in the table is selected, it will select all currently visible data rows (excl. header).

**Faster row deleting:**

After selecting the filtered rows to be deleted, many would be tempted to just hit the "del" key. However, this only blanks out the rows and will leave many empty rows between the kept rows. Instead click the "Delete" button on the Home ribbon, or right-click the row number and click "delete rows", or hit *ctrl* + *minus key* to delete whole rows entirely.

**Faster filtering:**
Filtering for all "FALSE" values in the "BLANK BELOW" column requires manually clicking the filter down arrow selection box (or *ALT* + *down arrow*), unchecking "Select all" and selecting "FALSE". The only way to do this faster requires the advanced filtering option accessed via the *alt* *a* *q* shortcut (press keys sequentially not together)). Advanced Filtering allows you to set the filter criteria permanently in a cell instead of clicking it in manually each time. Very convenient, but best explained on youtube.

Clearing the filter is quick and easy, just hit *alt* *a* *c* (sequentially).